# Prevent systemd unit from starting if a certain other unit is running

Tags: systemd

I have two systemd services `application.service` and `feh@.service`.
`application.service` is enabled and usually running.
`feh@.service` is not enabled and started only manually and has a `Conflicts=application.service` entry.

I want to achieve, that if `application.service` is running and I start an instance of `feh@.service`, that `application service` terminates.
This is currently working due to the `Conflicts=application.service` entry mentioned above.

However, a data synchronization service periodically restarts `application.service` via `systemctl restart application.service` remotely.
I would like this to fail if, and only if, `feh@.service` is running.
Currently this will shutdown the `feh@.service` instance and start `application.service`.
I could not find anything related to this in the official documents of systemd.

**Background info:**

I cannot let the remote service check for `feh@.service` because this only exists on a few machines (it is an exceptional configuration) and is not part of the usual infrastructure.
I also do not want to stop the service, since it also controls other devices that may not run `feh@.service`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had very similar problem; I would consider
[this response](https://serverfault.com/questions/1016586/prevent-a-systemd-service-from-starting-if-another-systemd-service-is-running) as the way to solve it; also I would test `After=` and `Before=` using `ExecStartPre=`